# When to use init() with delayed activity with Flurry on Android

Tags: android, flurry

I just started getting interested in Flurry, and there is things Im not sure about.
I have an application that start an activity when the screen is switched on (through a service), even when the application itself is not running. If I use the init() function in the Application class, as advised by Flurry's tutorial, do I still have to use it in the delayed activity, since the application is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `init()` in your Activity, especially as you are already calling it in your Application class. `FlurryAgent.init(Context, String)` is meant to be called once per entire application life-cycle.

What you *should* call in all your Activities is `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(Context)` to start a session. However, you do not need to call this if your application is targeting API 14+.

In your case, the Flurry SDK will be initialized in your Application class, but a session will only start after the `Activity#onStart()` method of your delayed Activity (i.e. when your Activity is on-screen).

You can read [Flurry docs](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/#add-calls-to-init-onstartsession-and-onendsession) to see where to place these calls.

Comment: Alright, thanks. But the flurry doc do say that there is no problem with calling init() more than once and just before onStartSession().

Comment: @Laetan there is no known adverse effect of calling it multiple times, but that is not the recommended usage. You initialize the SDK once and call `onStartSession()` in your Activities (or leave the SDK to call `onStartSession()` for running on API 14+